Any difference between context.object and context.active_object?
There are two similar context-related variables:

bpy.context.active_object

bpy.context.object


I don't see ANY difference between them,
but it seems quite logical, that one of them wouldn't exist if both being identical.
*API documentation does not explain them at all, while giving only return types.

So what's the difference between these two variables ?


Referencing a post by @Andrej on blenderartists. There may be other differences but AFAIK the main one is related to the use of the "pin" function in the top right of the properties panels to un-sync viewport selection and properties display.

Basically in case if operator or some UI panel is called from properties panel, it could make sense to use context.object instead of context.active_object.


The difference is context.active_object is the actual active object in the scene (context.view_layer.objects.active) and context.object is object in current properties panel.


In properties there is option to pin specific object’s properties and then after changing active object context.object won’t be the same as context.active_object (atleast for operators and panels called from the properties with the pinned object).


Clicking on a button in the right side panel will have context.object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"] and context.active_object = bpy.data.objects["Light"].
